# How to hide and show a view with the same button in Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, android-view, show-hide

For an android app I want to hide and show a view with the same button. It's probably a very basic understanding that I'm missing. So I would be really grateful for an explanation.

I've tried the code below, but it's only working once.

```
if (view1.isVisible){
        btnHideShow.setOnClickListener{
            view1.visibility = View.GONE
            if (view1.isGone) {
                btnHideShow.setOnClickListener {
                    view1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should set only 1 listener. Inside you check the current visibility. If visible you hide it, if hidden you show it.

Comment: `btnHideShow.setOnClickListener{ view1.isGone = !view1.isGone }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve that

btnHideShow.setOnClickListener{ view1.visibility = !view1.visibility  }

Comment: That's true! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment I found out it's easy like this:

```
btnHideShow.setOnClickListener{
        if (view1.isVisible){
            view1.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else view1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Correctly:

```
btnHideShow.setOnClickListener { view1.isVisible = !view1.isVisible }
```